# Do not want any blank entries appended to list jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to not allow any blank entries added to my list. I wrote the code and it seems to work fine. But I want to know is there a better way to write this. It just looks so weird to me that I feel like even though it works it just doesn't feel right. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
$("#item-add").keypress(function (enter){
        var press = enter.which;
        var addItem = $('#item-add').val();
        if(press == 13) {
            if (addItem == "") {            
            alert("You must enter an item to add to list.")
            $(".check-list").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="blank-box">' + addItem + '</li>');
            $('.blank-box').remove();
        } else {
            $(".check-list").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="check-box">' + addItem + '</li>');
        };
            $("#item-add").val('');
        } 
    });
```

Comment: better ask here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to add and remove `.blank-box` element, just use,

```
$("#item-add").keypress(function (enter) {
    var press = enter.which;
    var addItem = $('#item-add').val();
    if (press == 13) {
        if (addItem != "") {
           $(".check-list").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="check-box">' + addItem + '</li>');
        } else {
            alert("You must enter an item to add to list.")
        }
        $("#item-add").val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: oh duh!  != "" , don't know why I didn't think like that. Thanks so much for the fast response, I knew there was a shorter way to the madness I created lol.